# How to connect metamask account to remix (ropsten test)

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, remix, metamask

I have my `metamask` account working on the `Ropsten net`, and I have a contract I wrote working in `remix`.

However, when I select `web3` for the environment, I cannot figure out how to add my address to the "account" tab.

If you click on the add account button it gives me the below screen, however I cannot figure out what this is asking.

I tried entering my `metamask` password and that didn't work.

[image]